# Why can free throws be worth 2 or 3 points in the G League?

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

When I am watching NBA G. League games, it is very surprising that they give only one free throw in a situation where two or three free throws should have been given. Instead, each throw was considered two or three points respectively.

What is the reason for this unique rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is to speed up the game.

From a [CBS Sports](https://www.cbssports.com/nba/news/nba-g-league-reportedly-changes-free-throw-rule-single-shot-will-now-count-for-all-potential-points/) article by Sam Quinn in 2019 when the rule was introduced:

> **The goal of the new rule is to shave time off of games.** Basketball
> games typically have the shortest run-time among major professional
> sports, but according to Lowe, G League officials estimate that this
> move should cut around six to eight minutes from the league's average.
> The rule is being tested in the G League now ostensibly to see if it
> would be viable at the NBA level.

Answer (score 0):

The NBA uses the G League to experiment with new rules. This [free-throw rule](https://www.nba.com/news/g-league-experiment-free-throw-rule-official-release) is one of those experiments.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't really answer the question which is _why_ this rule was introduced.